# Spacing between flex items using flex-wrap

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm having issues displaying half width columns with **a varying space between** them using flexbox and **flex-wrap** to wrap them onto new lines.

**You can view a [Codepen example here](http://codepen.io/aaronvanston/pen/mAZvGP)**

The use-case involves being able to display full-length columns and half-columns within the same container. The half columns will get a modifier class that alters them to span 50% width and apply a margin to the right (only on odd or the left-hand column).

Ideally, it would work something like this:

[image]

I'm using BEM CSS so it looks a tad confusing, however, it pretty much does this on the half columns.

**Default col styles:**

```
.search-results__col {
    flex: 1;
    min-width: 100%;
}
```

**Split col overrides:**

```
search-results__col--half {
    max-width: 50%;
    min-width: 50%;
}
search-results__col--half:nth-child(odd) {
    margin-right:24px;
}
```

Is there a way to do this without using calc's on the max/min-widths for the half columns but rather have the width 50% (can be set via dynamic flex basis etc) take into account the margin? (I though flex basis might do this, but I have had no luck).

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no value of box-sizing that makes the margin being included in the width. I think calc is not really a bad solution.

Comment: @mm759 I'm concerned about performance issues with calc being re-calculated based on viewport size/resize

Comment: Don't calculations also take place when calc is not used? I mean there is a lot to calculate to render a typical web page.

Comment: @mm759 true, the solution does not really feel elegant setting both max and min to calc(50% - (gutter / 2)). I will give it ago and do some performance tests. Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: Here is a working example using a mixin to generate a calc for different viewports: http://codepen.io/aaronvanston/pen/ZpQdaP

Comment: instead of flexing along the row and wrapping them, the best thing to do here is to use `flex-direction: column` for the `search-reuslts__list` and wrap 'half columns' into another flexbox container...

Comment: @kukkuz thanks for your feedback! would this mean the half columns and full columns are not within the same parent? Ideally, they would be with in the same parent and then have logic to add the modifier if they should take full width or not.

Comment: Yes, the parent container will have full columns and containers that contains 2 half columns.... If you want it all under the same parent you are already doing it right `wrap`ing and applying `calc`...